# Calling arrow function component inside map has unexpected behavior

Tags: typescript, react-native, rerender

Using this simple example I can show you the problem I'm facing.
If I click multiple times in the FAB I want that the counter sum as fast as I click.
Using this Item as an arrow function component it just doesn't work, there's a delay between all clicks, because the component rerender on each click and the clicks are just computed after the rerender finishes.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { FAB, Text } from "react-native-paper";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function Home() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<{
    api_item_id: number;
    quantidade: number;
  }>(null);

  const addItem = async (apiItemID: number) => {
    setCounter((prevCounter) => {
      return {
        api_item_id: apiItemID,
        quantidade: (prevCounter?.quantidade || 0) + 1,
      };
    });
  };

  const Item = ({ item }: { item: { id: string; api_item_id: number } }) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{counter?.quantidade || 0}</Text>
      <FAB
        mode="flat"
        size="small"
        icon={"plus"}
        onPress={() => addItem(item.api_item_id)}
      />
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      edges={["bottom", "left", "right"]}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      {[{ id: "aasidagsisgd", api_item_id: 3 }].map((item) => (
        <View key={item.id}>
          <Text>{counter?.quantidade || 0}</Text>
          <FAB
            mode="flat"
            size="small"
            icon={"plus"}
            onPress={() => addItem(item.api_item_id)}
          />
        </View>
      ))}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

But when I replace the arrow function Item component and put it inline the maps it just works fine and as fast as I click.

```
{
  [{ id: "aasidagsisgd", api_item_id: 3 }].map((item) => (
    <View key={item.id}>
      <Text>{counter?.quantidade || 0}</Text>
      <FAB
        mode="flat"
        size="small"
        icon={"plus"}
        onPress={() => addItem(item.api_item_id)}
      />
    </View>
  ));
}
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?